# Hide social links when scrolling over certain images like on medium.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have medium and large images on a page and when my social links show up over these images I want to fade out the social links and fade back in when they are off the images. The amount of medium and large images will vary per page. You can see it working on a Medium.com post.

https://blog.fullstory.com/assess-customer-frustration-with-fullstory-rage-grade-497cf7b7aba1

The code below works just for the large images. When I try and add in medium images it doesn't work. My social links are fixed about 600px from the top. Thanks in advance!

```
var large_images = $('img[src*="#large"]'),
        medium_images = $('img[src*="#medium"]'),
        social = $('.social-share'),
        $window = $(window),
        showSocial = function() {
            if (isHidden) {
                isHidden = false;
                social.fadeIn(200);
            }
        },
        hideSocial = function() {
            if (!isHidden) {
                isHidden = true;
                social.fadeOut(200);
            }
        },
        isHidden = true,
        scrollTop;

    if (large_images.length) {
        $window.on('scroll', function() {
            var flag = false;

            scrollTop = $window.scrollTop() + 400;
            $.each(large_images, function(i, large_image) {
                var $large_image = $(large_image),
                    offset = $large_image.offset().top;

                if (offset < scrollTop && offset + $large_image.height() > scrollTop) {
                    flag = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            if (flag) {
                hideSocial();
            } else {
                showSocial();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: where's your html/css?

Comment: Try replacing `large_images = $('img[src*="#large"]'),
        medium_images = $('img[src*="#medium"]'),` with `all_images = $('img[src*="#large"],img[src*="#medium"]')` and then change the other 2 references to `large_images` to `images` in your jquery.

Comment: Where? I don't see any edits to your post...

Comment: Well dang. You are so right! Your edit fixed it perfectly!!! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I'll submit as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're only looping through `#large` images, you just need to also loop through `#medium` images. The logic you're using for `#large` should work fine with `#medium` images, assuming the only difference is the size.

You can replace your `large_images, medium_images` vars with `all_images = $('img[src*="#large"],img[src*="#medium"]')` and then change the other 2 references to `large_images` in your jquery to to `all_images`